# How to redirect to another format of the same controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, applicationcontroller

I've got this `index` method in my `TasksController`:

```
def index
  @tasks = current_account.tasks
  @count = @tasks.length
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      ...
    end
    format.zip do
      if @count > 100
        flash[:notice] = "Please reduce the number of tasks!"
        redirect_to :action => "index", :format => "html"
      else
        DownloadArchive.call(@tasks)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I render the `html` version of my index action if there are more than 100 tasks?

My code above doesn't work. Instead of redirecting and showing a flash message, it downloads the `html` file. I don't understand why. Please help me if you can.

Comment: The reason the html file is downloaded is that `format.zip` sets the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-tDisposition) header. So you override the header with `headers['Content-Disposition'] = "inline"`. But @lacostenycoder's answer is probally a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Format zip will download a file, whatever you pass in the block.  If you want to determine if the zip file should even be downloadable you'll need to do it before handling the format `zip` request.  You will probably need to change your view code to not show the download button or whatever it is that's handling the `zip` request.

```
def index
  @tasks = current_account.tasks
  @count = @tasks.length

  if @count > 100
    flash[:notice] = "Please reduce the number of tasks!"
    redirect_to :index and return
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      ...
    end
    format.zip do
        DownloadArchive.call(@tasks)
      end
    end
  end
end
```